# Is there a better way to use Jupyter IntSlider with Python Plotly?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets, plotly-python

In the following code block I use a Jupyter IntSlider to adjust the number of dots visualized in a Plotly express scatter 3d plot. The example already fits my use case, but I noticed that Plotly has [built-in slider functionalities](https://plot.ly/python/sliders/) that could improve the performance.

As a Plotly beginner I find it quite hard to map the slider example from Plotly to my use case.
Any suggestions?

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
from ipywidgets import interact, widgets

NUM_DOTS = 100
NUM_DIMS = 3

random_data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((NUM_DOTS,NUM_DIMS) ), columns=['x_1','x_2','x_3'])

def update_plotly(x):
    fig = px.scatter_3d(random_data[:x], x='x_1', y='x_2', z='x_3')
    fig.show()

interact(update_plotly, x=widgets.IntSlider(min=1, max=NUM_DOTS, step=1, value=NUM_DOTS))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it's not that hard to build the slider, just follow the path of the example shown by plotly:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

NUM_DOTS = 100
NUM_DIMS = 3

# Create figure
fig = go.Figure()

# Add traces, one for each slider step
for step in np.arange(1, NUM_DOTS, 1):

    #Random data
    random_data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((step, NUM_DIMS)), columns=['x_1','x_2','x_3'])

    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter3d(
            visible=False,
            line=dict(color="#00CED1", width=6),
            name=" = " + str(step),
            z=random_data['x_3'],
            x=random_data['x_1'],
            y=random_data['x_2']))

# Make 10th trace visible
fig.data[10].visible = True

# Create and add slider
steps = []
for i in range(len(fig.data)):
    step = dict(
        method="restyle",
        args=["visible", [False] * len(fig.data)],
    )
    step["args"][1][i] = True  # Toggle i'th trace to "visible"
    steps.append(step)

sliders = [dict(
    active=10,
    currentvalue={"prefix": "Frequency: "},
    pad={"t": 50},
    steps=steps
)]

fig.update_layout(
    sliders=sliders
)

fig.show()
```

resulting:

[image]

or with more points:

[image]

As you correctly figured out, it is way more performant than the widget slider, because with this method, you just toggle the trace visibility in the 3D Scatter chart.